# In asymptotic notation how to prove that $\mathcal{O}(g(n))\subseteq\mathcal{O}(f(n))\implies\mathcal{O}(f(n)+g(n))=\mathcal{O}(f(n))$

Tags: asymptotics, landau-notation

I have to prove that
 $$\mathcal{O}(g(n))\subseteq\mathcal{O}(f(n))\implies\mathcal{O}(f(n)+g(n))=\mathcal{O}(f(n))$$ 
The functions are non-negative.

**Clarification**: 
$$\mathcal{O}(f(n)+g(n))=\mathcal{O}(f(n))$$ 
it means 
$$\mathcal{O}(f(n)+g(n))\subseteq\mathcal{O}(f(n))\land\mathcal{O}(f(n))\subseteq\mathcal{O}(f(n)+g(n))$$

I try to explain my argument, i want to get on one side $f(n)+g(n)\in\mathcal{O}(f(n))$ and on the other: $f(n)\in\mathcal{O}(f(n)+g(n))$ in order to conclude that $\mathcal{O}(f(n)+g(n))=\mathcal{O}(f(n))$ true.

I start with the hypothesis:

$\mathcal{O}(g(n))\subseteq\mathcal{O}(f(n))\iff g(n)\in\mathcal{O}(f(n))$
$\iff(\exists c_1\in\mathbb{R}_{>0},n_0\in\mathbb{N}:g(n)\leq c_1f(n),\forall n\geq n_0) \implies$ 
$\{$adding $f(n)$ to both members of the inequality$\}$ $(\exists c_1\in\mathbb{R}_{>0},n_0\in\mathbb{N}:g(n)+f(n)\leq c_1f(n)+f(n),\forall n\geq n_0)\implies\quad(\exists c_1\in\mathbb{R}_{>0},n_0\in\mathbb{N}:g(n)+f(n)\leq (c_1+1)f(n),\forall n\geq n_0)\implies \{\textrm{taking}\quad c_1^{'}=(c_1+1)\}\quad  (\exists c_1^{'}\in\mathbb{R}_{>0},n_0\in\mathbb{N}:g(n)+f(n)\leq c_1^{'}f(n),\forall n\geq n_0)\iff \{by\quad definition\quad of \quad Oh-big \quad order\}\quad f(n)+g(n)\in\mathcal{O}(f(n))$

Now to achieve $f(n)\in\mathcal{O}(f(n)+g(n))$ start from the trivial proposition: $\mathcal{O}(f(n))\subseteq\mathcal{O}(f(n))$:

$\mathcal{O}(f(n))\subseteq\mathcal{O}(f(n))\iff f(n)\in\mathcal{O}(f(n))\iff(\exists c_2\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}, n_0\in\mathbb{N}:f(n)\leq c_2f(n),\forall n\geq n_0)\implies$ $\{$adding $g(n)$ to right member of inequality$\}\quad (\exists c_2\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}, n_0\in\mathbb{N}:f(n)\leq c_2f(n)+g(n),\forall n\geq n_0)$

At this point I'm stuck I don't know how to continue in order to achieve $f(n)\in\mathcal{O}(f(n)+g(n))$ to finish then the proof...

Thanks to everyone who read this :)

Comment: You seem to be using $O(f(n)+g(n))=f(n)$ and $f(n)=O(f(n)+g(n))$ to mean different things. They don't mean different things, so what do you mean?

Comment: sorry, i had copied and pasted at final f(n)+g(n) <= c2*f(n)+g(n) but is f(n) <= c2*f(n)+g(n), now corrected

Comment: Well, your way seems to be long and difficult. Why didn't you use the fact that $\exists c\in \mathbb{R^+}\ \forall g(n) \forall f(n) : g(n)\leq c\cdot f(n)$?

Comment: @JhonsonB. In your second paragraph, you say that you need to prove that $f\in O(f+g)$ to prove that $O(f+g) = f$. That's a tautology but the fact that you've written it suggests you think it isn't.

Comment: Excuse me my ignorance, but how is the formula even true? Even if g(n)=0, then f(n) is not identical to O(f(n)).

Comment: In another interpretation of "=", the formula is true even without the premise. That's why I don't understand.

Comment: @DavidRicherby, those two do mean different things. Frankly, the former makes no sense. The equality operator is an abuse of the notation and should **not** be taken to mean "is equal to" (check [notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Matters_of_notation)). Set notation would be a more proper expression. For example, $f(n) \in O(h(n))$. Here, $O(h(n))$ is a set of functions. Stating $O(h(n)) = f(n)$ is illogical because there's no good way to interpret this if $f(n)$ is a function.

Comment: @ryan "$f=O(h)$" is completely standard notation and everybody knows what it means. Since equality is symmetric, "$O(h)=f$" can only possibly mean exactly the same thing. Sure, it's a weird, nonstandard way to write it but to claim that it "makes no sense" or "is illogical because there's no good way to interpret this" is bizarre. You accept that there's a good way to interpret "$f=O(h)$" despite $f$ being a function and $O(h)$ being a set of functions. So how can it be that there's no good way to interpret the same "equality" written in the opposite order?

Comment: I'm voting to close as unclear, since the asker hasn't clarified what the introduction to their question is supposed to mean.

Comment: @DavidRicherby, yes it's standard usage and typically you don't come across these issues. I am saying this because the symbol $=$ does *not* represent equality in the case of $f = O(h)$. It can be misleading because it suggests a symmetry which it does not have. Reversing the sides could result in illogical deductions (e.g. $n = O(n^2)$ and $n^2 = O(n^2)$ would imply $n = n^2$ which it does not). Set notation is a more precise usage, we then have $f \in O(h)$, but $O(h) \in f$ or even $O(h) = f$ makes no sense because $f$ is a function.

Comment: When we say, e.g. $\mathcal{O}(f(n)) =\mathcal{O}(g(n))$, (f(n) and g(n) are non-negative) we say that: $\mathcal{O}(f(n))\subseteq\mathcal{O}(g(n))\land\mathcal{O}(g(n))\subseteq\mathcal{O}(f(n))$. And we never meant an abuse of notation like e.g. $f(n)\in\mathcal{O}(g(n))$

Comment: Sorry sorry I'm ashamed of me,  i had made a mistake with the latex formula in the heading.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are pretty much done.

$$
g(n) \ge 0 \implies f(n) \le f(n) + g(n), \quad \forall n \in \mathbb{N}
$$

So pick $c = 1 \in \mathbb{R}^+$ and $n_0 = 1 \in \mathbb{N}$, then
$$
f(n) \le c\cdot(f(n) + g(n)), \quad \forall n\ge n_0
$$

Comment: I think you should show that $f(n) + g(n) \leq cf(n)$ for fixed $c$ and $n > n_0$.

Comment: @tipanverella is right in this case.